# How to play sound and/or vibration on all mobile devices (phone gab, JQM & JS)

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, web-applications, phonegap-build

I am making a web app that includes a timer that counts down and alerts the user when it reaches 0. 
I found the functions navigator.vibrate(); and a similar one called beep. 
They work great in Chrome / Android, but are not supported in Safari & IE.
Is there any simple solution that works on both platforms?
Any kind of sound or vibration alert will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `navigator.vibrate()` it looks like it "pulses the vibration hardware on the device, if such hardware exists. If the device doesn't support vibration, this method has no effect." you could also try just a simple jquery alert `alert("Time is up");`

It doesn't look like beep is supported, so you would need to add something like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function PlaySound(soundObj) {
    var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
    sound.Play();
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

Comment: Thank you - it doesn't work in IOS though and I do need a sound or vibration to be fired.

Comment: Thank you again MannfromReno,
It makes the embedded audio play automatically even though autostart is set to false.
Something so simple - made so hard :-(

Comment: @JanBrage could you please post your code in your question, I can help you further to see what kind of javascript you have.

Comment: I actually totally removed the javascript for debugging - but it still fired the audio.

Comment: @JanBrage did you have `autostart="false"`? It should not automatically fire, if you just post your javascript and html I can help you debug further.

Comment: <embed src="alarm.mp3" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="alarm" enablejavascript="true">
I tried changing the false and true to 0 and 1 too.
put it  in the top of body, in head, below body, in html. I tried adding autoplay="false".
It fires even without any JS.

Comment: even like this: 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<embed src="sounds/alarm.mp3" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="alarm" enablejavascript="true">
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time ;-)